# Android: Figuring out the error in Eclipse with a red exclamation mark

Tags: android, compiler-errors

When I see a red exclamation mark in Eclipse next to my project name, how do I figure out what the error is? There is no error message. All I get is "Your project contains errors..."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to the Problems tab within eclipse, and a detailed list of any project errors will be available there.

If it's not open, go to: Window > show View > Problems

Comment: New window for me. I just upgraded to the latest version of the SDK. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help! I had the same issue as you and it took me a while to figure out how to locate it when no other windows showed it

Answer (score 1):

Its most likely a build path error. Right click on the project -> properties -> build path. Look for an error there.

Also, look at the error log...should pop up there.

Answer (score 0):

look for it into the console... or may be your drawable image name is having capital letters, spaces, or a minus sign. In res/drawable folder, only names with  0 to 9, a to z and underscore_ are allowed

Comment: Console is empty even after doing a clean.

Comment: ok, and what about the other tabs in that area (error log, problems) etc ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution. I had the same problem when I started.

You will see 3 tabs on the bottom. "Console", "Logcat", "Error"

> Logcat is most likely the best spot to find it if it is a arithmetic
>   error or something you wrote down was wrong. You may find the error line inside here as well.
>
> Error is the system errors in the system. Different requirements for
>   jars, or project requires this version and your this version.

Now if you can't find this 2. On the bottom left corner of the screen you will see a tiny column and a + symbol click it and get the error and logcat.

Comment: Oh yes derp :P forgot what was initially said.