# My R.Java is not generating may and project is not building using actiobarsherlock library

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

```
package com.yogeshbalan.myrootguide.appguide;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

this is my MainActivity and showing error 'Cannot resolve R to it's type '
    whenever i add actionbarsherlock library in my project it doesn't build, but build               after removing the library.

the error is

[Error Paste Bin](http://pastebin.com/edit.php?i=qXChxBAj)

Comment: Your project is failing to build because of some problems, which is why your R file is not generating. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11038770/1426565

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is usually caused by either of these possibilities:

- The most probable: You have a syntax error in any of your layout files (i.e., the files located under the *res\layout* folder of your project). The bad thing of this is that Eclipse won't warn you and tell you what's the error, so you'll have to go one by one looking for the syntax (probably an unmatched tag, an unmatched attribute, etc.) and fix the issue.
- The other possibility is a syntax error within your `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Same goes here, check it for syntax errors.

One of these two will fix your issue.

Comment: Just to add to this answer, it can also be caused by an illegal character in a file's name in your `res` folder.

Comment: Well, I am using android studio, but thanks i will try to find any hidden errors.